# Unintentional parallel minions

Tags: best-practices, sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

If the workload of a minion takes longer time than it's WakeupInterval, in order to avoid getting a second copy of the same minion processing the same list, is there a way to know if there is a previous process (from last time the minion got invoked) is still running so the first one can skip this wakeup?

Comment: I think this issue has been solved in Sitecore Commerce 9.0 update 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2019-04** - Commerce 9.1 resolves the reentrancy problems, just override `Minion.Execute` instead of `Minion.Run`. For a deep dive into the changes, I've written up an article [Reentrancy improvements to Minions in Sitecore Commerce 9.1](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2019/04/17/minion-reentry-improvements-in-sitecore-commerce-9-1/)

**Original answer (Commerce 9.0):**

First up, I consider the current behavior a bug since it directly conflicts with minions' primary usecase which is to process items from a queue. As such, I expect to it be fixed in a future version of Commerce so you might want to go with option 2 below.

Having said that, there are two ways you can go about solving this:

(note: all code is theoretical and untested - let me know if you run into any issues)

## Option 1: Skip reentrant calls

This isn't difficult to implement naively, and since minions will typically wait a certain amount of time before restarting you shouldn't have to worry about multithreaded access. Having said that, minions without a WakeupInterval run the risk of complicating this situation if their execution is delayed by the OS (or TPL).

If you want to deal with potential threading issues, the typical avenues are mostly off limits since `locks` are per thread and minions are started using `Task.Run` with `ConfigureAwait(false)` so awaits will almost certainly complete on a different thread than they started on. There are libraries that can handle this, but that seems overkill for this one-off usage.

With all that in mind, here's a base class that uses `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to safely skip reentrant calls:

```
public abstract class NonReentrantMinion
{
    private int isRunning = 0;

    public abstract Task<MinionRunResultsModel> SafeRun();

    public override async Task<MinionRunResultsModel> Run()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRunning, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            // Log skipped invocation
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            return await SafeRun();
        }
        finally
        {
            isRunning = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: `isRunning` is intentionally non-static since Minions are singletons per Policy, which is likely inline with how you'd want the reentrancy to work.

## Option 2: Queue the WakeupInterval delay

Since most minions continue to drain their managed list until it's empty, making it essentially pointless to invoke it again immediately afterwards, I consider this option to be the "fix `Minion.Start`" approach.

```
public abstract class SerialMinion
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    await this.Run();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Prevent exceptions from breaking the loop
                    // (not logged since the base implementation doesn't either)
                }

                if (this.Policy.WakeupInterval.HasValue)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(this.Policy.WakeupInterval.Value);
                }
            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I will check with my colleagues which of your soulutions we should try first. I'm sure either one of them will solve my problem.

Comment: Np. If it does resolve your issue, consider marking it as "the answer" so other users don't try to follow up.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I have had a chance to try to implement and test it. I can't promice I get a chance at it today though.

Comment: I have now successfully implemented and tested the first of your solutions and it do solve my issue. Thank you for your assistance.